# Server Not Found error on some servers

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, internet, internet-connection

I'm using Windows 7 64-bit and Ubuntu . My hosts file is empty. I'm using Firefox and Internet Explorer.

When I tried to visit some sites I get a **Server Not Found** error. If I refresh the page a few times, it's working.

However some sites (for example cloudfront.net) aren't working outright.

I have also tried it with OpenDNS with the same result, and on two different locations.

What do you think the problem might be, and how could I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Under Windows, check the event logs using Event Viewer. Under the DNS-Client, it should say the DNS query timed out if it is a DNS problem.If it isn't a DNS problem, then you'll need to run some more tests the next time this happens.

The next time it happens, you'll need to use `nslookup` to send a DNS query.  Narrow down the causes. Without more information, we might as well be sifting through a haystack . . .

Comment: Hello,There isn't any error for DNS-Client . This is the result of `nslookup`: `Varsay²lan Sunucu
Address:  8.8.8.8`

Comment: If the DNS resolver is getting an IP address, but the server behind the IP address doesn't respond, there is little you can do in that case.